# Include inherited base class member in derived class' member union

Tags: c++, inheritance, unions

Suppose there exists a base class as follows:

```
class foo
{
    int x0;//private variable should not be a participant in derived union
           //(unless bar is a friend)
protected:
    int x1;
};
```

And a derived class which inherits it:

```
class bar : foo
{
protected:
    union
    {
        //int foo::x1;
        char[4] x2;
    };
};
```

I want to put the base member `x1` and re-use its space inside the member union of the derived class.

Typically derived classes can play with the base class members and do any thing except re-use their space.

---

### Questions

1. Is this possible using any "magic" and still be safe from UB?
2. If not possible, are there any reasons why this may be considered seriously wrong?
3. Will it be possible (if at all) to extend this to a nameless struct inside the union to hold the base member?

***EDIT:*** By "magic", I do not mean any vendor specific extensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
class bar : foo
{
protected:
    char* x2() { return reinterpret_cast<char*>(&x1); }
};
```

This is allowed because strict aliasing has an exception for `char*`.

I don't think there's much you can do beyond that (e.g. if you want to use types other than `char*`), short of rearranging the class hierarchy to split the unionable parts from the non-unionable parts of `foo`.

Comment: Hmmm this depends on whether using `char[4]` as an example was just a coincidence.  Also...  16-bit int.  =P

Comment: I wish to be able to this with wchar_t as well, like as in wchar_t[2] x2. My ints are 32-bit though

Comment: @AnirbanSarkar: Can you change it so it's `char[4]` in the base class, then reinterpret it as `int`, `wchar_t[2]`, etc. in the derived class?

Comment: @JohnZwinck Well the whole point of being able to do it in the union was to simplify the code that is without having to resort to things like `memcpy` or `reinterpret_cast`.    I have a solution, just that it's not so elegant.

Comment: @AnirbanSarkar: There is nothing elegant about unions in C++.  :)  I'd stick with whatever you have.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Well, you can use a variable by the name, so the code is small and although I like to play Einstein in my code, I'd rather not. ;) The problem however of reusing a base member's space is interesting though. It seems like a flaw to me but maybe there are better reasons to avoid it. Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Comment: @AnirbanSarkar: Speaking of reasons to avoid it, did you know that `x1` need not follow `x0`?  When two variables have an access specifier between them (`protected` in this case), the usual rules about member ordering no longer apply.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Wow, I did not know that. Gotta, read the standard. :)